# Beginner with AHK: When I try to sleep a random amount of time, it always sleeps the maximum amount

Tags: autohotkey

To start off, I am a big noob when it comes to AHK.

When I want to sleep a random amount of seconds with this variable: random rand, 0, 3000 it always sleeps for 3000. I can't figure out why. I've searched on multiple forums but most of the times the code provided in the slolution is too complicated for me to understand. Sidenote: Do you guys know of any good youtube tutorial series aimed at beginners?

I followed the exact steps from this comment:

https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/3o5trp/how_to_do_a_random_sleep_in_ahkautohotkey/cvuenc1/

This is my code:

```
pause on

random rand, 0, 3000    
mousemove, 100,100,20,r    
sleep %rand%    
mousemove, 100,100,20,r    
sleep %rand%    
mousemove, 100,100,20,r    
sleep %rand%    
mousemove, 100,100,20,r    
sleep %rand%    


return    

z:: pause    
x:: exitapp    
c:: return
```

The `mousemove` is just a placeholder to test the random sleeping. Between every 0 and 3 seconds randomly I expect the mouse to move. Now it only does it every 3 seconds exactly.

Lastly: As I am new to stack overflow, so If you can give me some suggestions to format my post better feel free to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some more googling and help from a friend, I'm now with the following code:
It seems to work now, and it's also looped 50 times. Recommendations to improve the code are welcome.

```
pause on


rnd(min,max){
    Random, myVar,% min,% max
return myVar
}    


loop
{
    if x >=50
        break
    else       
        mousemove, 100, 100, 10, r
        Sleep, % rnd(1,2000)
        x++        
}       


Return    

z:: pause
x:: exitapp
c:: return
```

Comment: In your earlier example you defined the sleeping time only once and (re)used it everywhere, in your 2nd example you call your function rnd() everytime you need it, thus giving you different values. Just so you start to understand why this works differenly.

Comment: A couple of other things I noticed that could clean it up a little: (1) No need for `Else` in this case. (2) Loops have a built-in counter `A_Index`, so you could replace `x` with `A_Index` in your if-statement and delete `x++`. (If using `A_Index`, you would also want to change ">=" to ">" since it has the iteration value at the start of the loop; otherwise, it will only loop 49 times.)